# In vim what would \>the\< match to

Tags: regex, vim, word-boundary

In vim what would
`\>the\<`,
`\>the`, or
`the\<`
match to?

I know `\<the\>` will match to `"Other than the every thing else"` and not `"You are still exploring"`

Answer (score 4):

Your patterns would match nothing.

If we look at it literally, `\>the` would match "`the` right after the end of a word" but there's no such thing as "a word right after a word": they would be *the same word*.

Same reasoning for "a word just before a word" and "a word between two words".

Comment: isn't that those are word boundaries?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yes, they are word boundaries and that's why the proposed patterns wouldn't match anything. A word following or preceding a word is just the same word so there's no word boundary.

Comment: @romainl, what would be the point of having `\>` and `\<` as two different word boundaries when one always uses `\<USELESS\>` format, should'nt `\b` be enough and then `\<`, `\>` and `\b` would mean the same thing

Comment: `\<` and `\>` are more expressive than `\b` because the formers are explicit while the latter is implicit. Anyway, `\<` and `\>` were already in `ex` and `vi` which predate Perl by a good decade and PCRE by two so… go ask Bill Joy. Maybe he will be able to explain why he stubbornly chose to not follow a "standard"… that didn't exist at that time.